# How to limit a string not to hurt HTML code, in Php?

Tags: php, html

I have a big problem. I must cut a string which consists HTML code. But I have no idea how to do it so that HTML code wont get damage:

```
<p>this is a <strong>HTML</strong> code which is too long, and can be even UNICODE characters</p>
```

with mb_substr():

```
<p>this is a <strong>HTM
```

is there a way solving it out?

Comment: use `strip_tags` see http://in2.php.net/strip_tags and after that use `substr`

Comment: It can't be done in a deterministic way. You can use libraries like `simple_html_dom` to iteratively cut and check if shorter string is still valid HTML. Apart from that you should first limit string length, not shorten it later. :)

Comment: Function `strip_tags` can't be used because he needs to "HTML code wont get damaged".

Comment: @John Smith, the question is `Why do you want cut it?`. Because if it is only a preview of a text on your website, there are CSS rules that can make this for you in a very nice way.

Comment: Jurik, I know, but I have to add dots at the end, which cant be done if a text exceeds a box (anyhow)

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse your string. I'd do something like a split using regex and then cut the string (count the characters without the tags) and then add closetags again.

Try this to cut after 10 characters and works only for the first occurence:

```
$cut_after = 10;
$string_complete = "<b>Peter Griffin</b>";
$string_to_cut   = filter_var($string_complete, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
var_dump($string_complete);
//string '<b>Peter Griffin</b>' (length=20)

$string_chopped_head = substr($string_to_cut, 0, $cut_after);
$string_chopped_tail = substr($string_to_cut, $cut_after, (strlen($string_to_cut)-$cut_after));
$string_head_before_cut = substr($string_complete, 0, stripos($string_complete, $string_chopped_head));
$string_tail_after_cut = substr($string_complete, stripos($string_complete, $string_chopped_tail)+strlen($string_chopped_tail));

$final_string = $string_head_before_cut . $string_chopped_head . $string_tail_after_cut;
var_dump($final_string);
//string '<b>Peter Grif</b>' (length=17)
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the tools you can use to solve that out: [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the position of the tags, `strlen($string)` to calculate the lenght of the string, and [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the pieces of the string.

Answer (score 1):

filter the string before cutting by using FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING